# Как задействовать кнопку ok на виртуальной клавиатуре android?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, написал программу которая при нажатие на кнопку onClickButton выводит текстовое поле в котором можно писать текст с помощью виртуальной клавиатуры, но когда текст написан при нажатии на кнопку OK что бы его применить ни чего не происходит. Приходиться в ручную убирать клавиатуру и что бы применить написанный текст нужно ещё раз нажать на кнопку onClickButton.

```
 public void onClickButton(View view) {


    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(informationAboutFile)){//если informationAboutFile содержит ноль

        mAutoComplete.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.VISIBLE);

    }


 informationAboutFile = mAutoComplete.getText().toString();// инфу с mAutoComplete помещаем в informationAboutFile

 if (flag == true){

 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(informationAboutFile)) {//если informationAboutFile не пустой

        mAutoComplete.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.INVISIBLE);


        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);// Намерение для запуска камеры
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, generateFileUri(TYPE_PHOTO));
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);// Намерение для запуска камеры

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // Выводим сообщение об ошибке
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.message2,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast1.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Пробую сделать так то есть присвоить переменной flag = true и в звасимести от этого произвести действия но результата нет.

```
 public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        // обрабатываем нажатие кнопки DONE

        flag = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}/**/
```

Comment: Так вам надо, чтобы клавиатура не закрывала кнопку или сделать кнопку на клавиатуре?

Comment: Кстати, зачем вы видимость ставите по `AutoCom....VISIBLE` если можно просто `View.VISIBLE`

Comment: @СергейГрушин так кнопка на клавиатуре есть OK  нажимаешь её и ни чего не происходит. Мне нужно что бы при её нажатии запись помещалась в переменную всё закрывалось и делались дальнейшие действия.

Comment: добавил в ответ, мелочь пропустил и ничего не работало

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за помощь, всё заработало)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Колбэк `onKeyDown()` срабатывает только на нажатия механических (аппаратных) кнопок и на кнопки виртуальной клавиатуры его действие не распространяется.

Вам нужно установить прослушивание кнопки Enter с помощью `OnEditorActionListener`/ Слушатель в колбэке вернет `actionId` - в каком именно виде находится кнопка Enter. Доступные варианты [состояний actionID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#constants)

```
editOK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
editOK.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // обрабатываем нажатие кнопки DONE

            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Для поля ввода должно быть обязательно установлено одно из состояний `inputType` (кроме `none`):

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/editText"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:inputType="text"/>
```

Если на кнопке ENTER нужен другой текст (например OK вместо DONE) то для поля ввода устанавливаем свой imeOption:

```
editOK.setImeActionLabel("OK", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

[Подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/keyboard.php) про работу с клавиатурой

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как получить результат из onEditorAction вы не могли бы мне пояснить ?

Comment: @VargSieg о каком результате в хотите узнать

Comment: Результат нажатия клавиши, я ваш пример переделал под mAutoComplete.setOnEditorActionListener(this), метод boolean onEditorAction должен вернуть true если ID совпадают, но в куда он его возвращает  вызвать в другом методе я его не могу как взывают методы onEditorAction() нужно прописать параметры и ещё вопрос возможно ли использовать onKeyDown

Comment: прописывайте свои параметры туда, где написано *// обрабатываем нажатие кнопки DONE*. true он возвращает для системы, а не для вас - значит, что обработка нажатия уже выполнена и системе не требуется обрабатывать нажатие на эту кнопку. Для чего использовать onKeyDown?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, взгляните пожалуйста в чём может быть причина ?