# Как отловить нажатие на Enter для EditText на стандартной клавиатуре андроид?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Или каким образом можно динамично реагировать на ввод символов в  EditText ?

Comment: При помощи `TextWatcher`.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605721/177345

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отловить нажатие Enter (или других клавищ, таких как Search, Done и т.п.):

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Чтобы динамически реагировать на ввод пользователя:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                 //ваши действия
            }
        });
```