# Как отловить нажатие enter и перехода на новую строку в editText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу отловить нажатие enter и перехода на новую строку в editText multilite.

Пробовал:

```
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if( event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                // обработка нажатия Enter
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Не работает.

Comment: Не подскажете куда этот листенер вставлять в коде? в какую функцию?

Comment: в смысле в какую функцию? вешаете на тот edittext, в котором нужно перехватить enter

Comment: Но как его "Повесить". У меня объявлен 
EditText edittext;
Дальше куда этот код который у него? в OnCreate или куда? я просто не делал это еще не понимаю как это работает

Comment: Что уже сделано? добавьте в вопрос код разметки, где этот edittext и код активити.

Comment: насчет того, что у вас в вопросе смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605721/177345)

Comment: Понял спасибо, нужно было через implements добавить вот эту функцию

 @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
}


Если что о ней спрашивал)